# Troubleshooting Font Awesome not working in Chrome on WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, font-awesome

My Font Awesome icons are loading in Firefox and Safari, but not in Chrome.

I have added the following lines to my webserver's .htaccess file before cleared my browser's cache and restarting/ reloading apache:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule> 
</FilesMatch>
```

This is what inspect tells me:

```
Font from origin 'https://www.portalpay.io' has been blocked from loading
by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'https://portalpay.io' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am using WordPress running on Digital Ocean Ubuntu 12.04 droplet with apache. I also tried adding some  lines to htaccess, but that prevented the site from loading.

Comment: I have noticed that apache has been giving me warnings: AH00558

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried adding some lines to htaccess

You don't need to do that.

> Font from origin `https://www.portalpay.io` has been blocked from loading
>   by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: 
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
>   Origin `https://portalpay.io` is therefore not allowed access.

The problem here simply is that you load your site via `https://portalpay.io`, but then try to load the font from `https://www.portalpay.io` - which are different origins.

Yes, sending an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the font resource's response would fix that - but the much easier solution is to load your font from the same address as your site itself.

So go check your stylesheet or font loader for where it tries to request the font from the www address, and replace it with the non www version.

Comment: Thanks mate! You gave me the idea to change the "WordPress Address (URL)" in https://portalpay.io/wp-admin/options-general.php I removed the www and it works now =)

Comment: Although I did have to leave those htaccess lines in there in order to keep it working in firefox

Comment: I know Firefox is fussy about cross origin webfont loading - but if they are actually loaded via the exact same protocol, domain and port as the page, then it should work fine, without any additional CORS headers (because no CO involved) - are you sure what you are seeing is not just a caching issue?